# Using any nvidia-* package causes system to hang on boot

Tags: 13.04, nvidia

I'm using a GeForce GTX 660 on a custom built system. The nouveau driver works properly and I can use Ubuntu normally with it. However I'd like to use NVIDIA's driver.

I have not really found an official guide for this so I'm sort of winging it.

I've seen suggestions to install packages from Ubuntu Software Center, but nothing appears in the "Additional Drivers" tab, so I'm doing this all from apt.

I've attempted to install nvidia-304, nvidia-319 (the one I expect would work), and nvidia-331 (from xorg-edgers just for the hell of it). They all have the same result: after making my selection in grub, it behaves as though it's about to boot but hangs at a solid dark purple screen. If I remove 'quiet' from the boot parameters, it hangs at two brief messages citing which kernel it's loading. If I set vga=vesa:off I see the usual boot messages, though it hangs all the same with nothing of note in the logs.

My current kernel is 3.8.0-31-generic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It may have been one of two things for me, but here's what I did to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

I kind of doubt the driver version had anything to do with the problem. I previously had not tried the 313 version before, but it appears to be available in a vanilla Ubuntu install. I suspect later versions of the driver should work, but this one I believe will be good enough for me.

I noticed that I did not have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` installed on my machine by default after installing these packages, so I ran the `nvidia-xconfig` utility to generate one. I think this had more of a hand in the fix.